# How to stop Xcode from automatically adding close quotes, parentheses, and braces when typing in a plain text file?

Tags: xcode

I have a plain text file in my Xcode project I use to make notes as I work.

One really annoying "feature" of Xcode is its insistence on adding a matching `'`, `"`, `}`, or `)` if I type a `'`, `"`, `{`, or `(` respectively, followed by another character.

For example, if I simply want to type the word `it's`, then after I've entered the `it'`, as soon as I type the `s`, Xcode automatically adds a "closing apostrophe" and I end up with `it's'`. And when I don't notice and continue typing, I end up with something like `it's an annoying feature'` (note the extraneous `'` at the end).

How can I turn off this feature, at least for plain text files?

I've been through all of the settings and I've looked through the Editor menu but I can't see anything relevant.

The only thing I've found is in the key bindings there is a binding for Ctrl-' (`^'`) mapped to "Insert Single Quote without Extra Action (Insertions and Indentations)". But this doesn't seem to apply in my example. If I type `it`, then Ctrl-', then `s`, I still get the extraneous `'` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this behavior under Preferences - Text Editing - Editing - "Enable Typeover Completions" (uncheck)

Comment: This does in fact stop Xcode from automatically adding a closing `'`, `"`, and `)` (maybe others, just checked those). But it also stops that behavior everywhere, including in code where it is useful. I really wish there was a way to set this only for plain text files. I also wish Apple provided some documentation somewhere (I searched, but no luck) so I could know everything that setting changes.